# Broken versioning for master pages and style library

Tags: master-page, sharepoint-online, versioning, style-library

This has been frustrating me for a while.

When I look at the master page library or the style library on my SharePoint site I see that versioning is in place. However, the site itself always loads version 1.0 of the document, when I am currently on version 22.0. I have tried clearing my cache and cookies and reloading the site, but it still loads version one.

The only work-around I have found is to name my new version master_page_V22.master (or something like that) and adding it to the library. The same applies to the style library where I have everything from custom_style.css to custom_style_v19.css. It's even more frustrating with the style library because whenever I update a .css file or a .js file, I have to make a new version of the master page.

It just seems to be counter-intuitive to make new files every time and fill up these libraries when versioning is clearly in place. I have downloaded the newest versions of the file and they are correct too, it's just that the site/browser refuses to acknowledge the changes.

Comment: Do you have approval turned on? If so is any of the later versions approved?

Comment: Yes, approval is turned on, for the master pages. I publish the file and then approve it right after. The items in the style library do not have approval turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'the site itself' I assume you mean that people other than you only see version 1.0.  In which case, I would suggest that you make sure you are Publishing your versions, not merely checking them in.

Comment: By "the site itself" I mean when I go to www.[site].com, it is displaying elements and styles from version one in the browser. For me and for everyone. And they are being published, because like I said, my original document's version history says it's at 6.0 because that's about when I gave up and just started creating new files.

Comment: Do you have two different URLs that you use to access your site?  If so, can you verify that they are pointing to the same content database?  I have seen cases where two sites were created based on copies of the same database and people mistakenly thought they really were the same.

Comment: I don't believe that I have multiple URLs. Especially since I upload a new version of the document, publish it, and hit refresh and don't see the change. Same if I do a ctrl+F5 to clear cache and refresh.

Comment: This is extremely unusual behavior which sounds like there is something unique in your configuration.  Can you verify that the Page Output Cache is disabled? You might also want to check your browser and verify that your Browser History Settings didn't get accidentally set to 'Never'

Comment: ... when you Publish, does it start a workflow?

Comment: No, publishing these items does not start a workflow. My browser was set to check for new versions of pages automatically. I just set it to check for never versions every time I visit the page, but I'm still getting the same issue. I'm not sure how to check the Page Output Cache. I don't have access to SharePoint Server (which is what Google tells me I need to look at).

Comment: For development purposes you should probably set your browser to 'Every Time' so that it is always getting fresh content.  The Page Output Cache is in Site Settings under Site Collection Administration

Comment: Yeah, output cache is disabled, and like I said it is automatically checking for new content...still pulling version 1.0 of a javascript file when I have it published as version 2.0

Comment: Just out of curiousity, can you modify your master page and add a querystring parameter to your js include?  Somthing like `myfile.js?r=2.0` with the `r=2/0` being the new part.  I'm wondering if you are hitting a known caching bug

Comment: Actually, it turns out I had edited the wrong file. My bad.

Looks like setting IE to check for a new version every time may have done the trick. I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer due to the comment chain. Thanks, Dave!